# SVG clippath viewbox not working

Tags: html, css, svg

I am attempting to add an SVG clippath to a div element.

I want the clippath to span the full div element.

I gave the SVG a viewbox and gave the clippath polygons points within this viewbox.

However, the polygons do not seem to adjust their height and width's based on the viewbox or the container's height and width. It remains static.

How do I get this to work? Here is my SVG code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
    <clipPath id="svgClip">
        <polygon points="0 0 0 100 100 100"/>
    </clipPath>
    <path id="svgMask">
        <polygon points="0 0 0 100 100 100"/>
    </path>
</svg>
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="div11"></div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.div11{
   background: url(http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  z-index: 5000;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(clip.svg);
  clip-path: url(clip.svg#svgClip);
  -webkit-mask: url(clip.svg);}
```

Please help! Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xhh7a/3/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for. It's sized to the shape, at least it was when I ran it in Firefox.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <clipPath id="svgClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <polygon points="0 0 0 1 1 1"/>
    </clipPath>
    <path id="svgMask" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <polygon points="0 0 0 1 1 1"/>
    </path>
</svg>
<div class="div11"></div>
```

Comment: Do you know why this does not work in chrome, and it only works in firefox?

Comment: In firefox it works brilliantly, but in Chrome the screen is just blank.

Comment: Firefox uses clip-path, Chrome uses -webkit-clip-path as it doesn't support clip-path on non-SVG elements. Maybe you're using -webkit-clip-path incorrectly. I don't really know how -webkit-clip-path is supposed to work.